# ReportViewer displaying black background in Print Layout mode

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportviewer

In my ReportViewer control, when I click on Print Layout, the background turns black on the report. This must be a bug. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft was already aware of this issue, its KB is located [here](http://blog.n-technologies.be/ct.ashx?id=dfa6b270-0143-4389-9f5d-725b8eb95d3c&url=http%3a%2f%2fsupport.microsoft.com%2fkb%2f935436).

You can solve the problem by installing Cumulative Update 1 (build 3161), which can be requested for download through the following Microsoft [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935356/en-us)

If you can wait a little while more I think the fix will come out with SQL Server 2005 SP3